# React Native Linking eventListener crashes with deep linking

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I am trying to implement deep linking/universal linking with my React Native app and it works good so far, but one thing. I have an `eventListener` and `getInitialUrl` in my `app.js` like so:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    Linking.addEventListener("url", (url) => handleInvite(url));
    Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => handleInvite(url));
  }, []);
```

`getInitialUrl` works fine and the app opens and gets the url. This function is when the app is not active in the background. However, when the app is in the background the `eventListener` gets fired and the app crashes immediately. I tested it with and without and the problem is the `eventListener`, but I don't know why.

The app crashes immediately and I can't find any info on this problem. So any help would be much appreciated.

This is tested on iOS.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the eventListener on unmount ?
ie:
 ` useEffect(() => {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', handleInvite);
    return () => Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleInvite);
  }, []);`

Comment: @Blimeys, thanks I will try this. But how do I get the URL in that function?

Comment: I would create another hook to handle  Linking.getInitialURL() those are two very separate events, even if the url is similar. You can then prioritise the value you want to use inside a context with a useReducer for example

Comment: @Blimeys, I found the error and it was on my end. Basically the addEventListener returns an array and not a string. So when using that in the function it caused the app to crash.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem. Basically the `addEventListener` returns an array and not a string. So when using that in the function it caused the app to crash.

The right way to add the `eventListener` is like this:

```
Linking.addEventListener("url", event => handleInvite(event.url));
```

It is weird that no where in the docs this example is given. But it works now atleast!